# Silverlight trying to Bind before properties are set

Tags: silverlight, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm quite new to xaml and I' trying to bind properties from a custom class to apply a theme system but xaml tries to bind before my properties are set. I am also unable to get INotifyPropertyChanged to work with my custom class and I would like to allow users to switch themes on the fly.

my (simplified) code:

```
public class clsThemeObjects : DependencyObject, ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;
    public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e);

    public SolidColorBrush ButtonTextBrush {
    get {
            return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ButtonTextBrushProperty);
        }
        set {
            SetValue(ButtonTextBrushProperty, value);
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ButtonTextBrush"));
        }
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonTextBrush", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(cls_Globals), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}

static class Globals
{ 
    static  ThemeObjects = new clsThemeObjects();
    public Globals()
    {
        ApplyTheme();
    }

    Public static void ApplyTheme()
    {
        ThemeObjects.ButtonTextBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
}
```

in my xaml I'm doing this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonBlankStyle}" Grid.Row="2" Name="btnAddModules"         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="2" Margin="0,4">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="{Binding Path=ButtonTextBrush, Source={StaticResource ThemeObjects}}" />
    </Border>
</Button>
```

I thought that using iNotifyPropertyChanged would work but it doesn't, can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declared static ThemeObjects = new clsThemeObjects(); in static class it doesn't mean that you have access to it from XAML using StaticResource markup extension. You should declare it as resource in XAML to do that. Please, read more about [StaticResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189045%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)